# Run Function Based on File Input Status

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-io

I have two file upload inputs on a page and I am trying to check if a file has been selected for those inputs. If a file is selected run the code, otherwise do nothing.

Below is my code:

```
<input id="file1" type="file" class="file1" />
<input id="file2" type="file" class="file2" />

<button class="upload radius small">Upload</button>

$(function() {
  if ($("#file1").val()) { 
    //Run code if file input is selected. Otherwise do nothing...   
  }
  if ($("#file2").val()) { 
    //Run code if file input is selected. Otherwise do nothing...   
  }
});
```

When I try the above code it doesn't work. No errors are thrown, it just doesn't work. How do I fix the problem?

Note: I am using jQuery 2.1.

Comment: Well, since your JavaScript is most likely executing before any files are selected, `.val()` will return "" and the `if` statements won't execute. Your code is set to run when the DOM is ready, and I doubt the user has selected a file by then

Comment: **When** do you want your code to run? After a file is selected? After a button is clicked?

Comment: If you want it to run when the upload button is clicked, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/PsZNY/ - you need to listen for the button to be clicked

Comment: @Ian - Take your comments and put as an answer. I realized after your comment to listen for the button click. It is working now. =>

Comment: You can also listen for the on change for the file `$('#file1').on('change',function(){//do something})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is set to run when the DOM is ready (signified by being wrapped with `$(function () { /* CODE */ });`), and I doubt the user has selected a file by then. It seems that you want to run your code when the upload button is clicked. That means you need to bind a `click` event for it. Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("button.upload").on("click", function () {
        if ($("#file1").val()) { 
            console.log("File 1 set"); 
        }
        if ($("#file2").val()) { 
            console.log("File 2 set"); 
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/PsZNY/

I left the `$(function() {});` to ensure the upload button can be found by jQuery (when the DOM is ready).

---

**References:**

- `$().on` - https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

You will need an event handler to check if something is uploaded, at the time user is uploading, e.g.: check if input has value when the input is 'changing':

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#file1").change(function (){
      if ($("#file1").val()) { 
        console.log('file1 uploaded');
      }
    });
    $("#file1").change(function (){
      if ($("#file2").val()) { 
        console.log('file2 uploaded');
      }
    });
});
</script>
```